# Wrong Data Type in Function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting the ever so annoying "A value used in this formula is the wrong data type." error and I can't for the life of me figure out what is causing it.

```
Public Function Cc(q As Double, ID As Double) As Double

Dim YP As Double            'lb/100ft^2
Dim Fan600 As Single
Dim Fan300 As Single
Dim n As Double             'Flow behavior index
Dim K As Double             'Consistency index

Dim Form As Worksheet
Set Form = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ECD Generator")

'=========================================================================================================

YP = Form.Cells(5, 10).Value
Fan600 = Form.Cells(6, 10).Value
Fan300 = Form.Cells(7, 10).Value

'=========================================================================================================

n = 3.32 * WorksheetFunction.Log10(Fan600 / Fan300)
K = 5.1 * Fan600 / (1022 ^ n)

Cc = 1 - (1 / (2 * n + 1)) * (YP / (YP + K * ((3 * n + 1) * q / (n * WorksheetFunction.Pi * (ID / 2) ^ 3)) ^ n))

End Function
```

Comment: What line is the error appearing on? Presumably `n = 3.32 * WorksheetFunction.Log10(Fan600 / Fan300)`?

Comment: I believe within the Cc=...

Comment: If i break it at Cc= everything seems to be running fine so far. n and k are calculated

Comment: Consider using `Log(Fan600 / Fan300) / Log(10)` for better portability (and perhaps performance).

Comment: Can you tell us the line it fails on using F8 please, I believe its `n = 3.32 * WorksheetFunction.Log10(Fan600 / Fan300)` because you have two `Singles` dividing then being used as a double. But it could also be that `WorksheetFunction.Pi` should have brackets at the end `WorksheetFunction.Pi()`. We need more information to answer.

Comment: i made both of those changes and still getting the error. The error is certainly coming from the Cc = 1 - (1 / (2 * n + 1)) * (YP / (YP + K * ((3 * n + 1) * q / (n * WorksheetFunction.Pi() * (ID / 2) ^ 3)) ^ n))

Comment: sorry first time actually posting not sure how to make that appear as code

Comment: At the points of failure can you let us know what the values of `n`, `YP`, `K`, `q`, and `ID` are. That should give us the answer to the issue.

Comment: n=0.414796605539556 k=1.15164904371769 YP=2 ID=4.276 q=598.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running this code in Excel 2013, the `Cc = ...` expression throws an "Expression too complex" error.  Simplify the expression by using temporary variables:

```
n = 3.32 * WorksheetFunction.Log10(Fan600 / Fan300)
K = 5.1 * Fan600 / (1022 ^ n)

'Add these temp variables to make the "Cc = ..." expression less complex.

Dim t1 As Double
t1 = 1 / (2 * n + 1)

Dim t2 As Double
t2 = n * WorksheetFunction.Pi * (ID / 2) ^ 3

Cc = 1 - t1 * (YP / (YP + K * ((3 * n + 1) * q / t2) ^ n))
'Cc = 1 - (1 / (2 * n + 1)) * (YP / (YP + K * ((3 * n + 1) * q / (n * WorksheetFunction.Pi * (ID / 2) ^ 3)) ^ n))
```

Comment: Thanks! does that error just pop up when equations get too long sometimes?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with VBA.  But I do know it has some "interesting" behaviors that aren't present in most other languages.

Answer (score 3):

With the values you supplied in the comments I got a different error of

> 16: Expression too complex

Information on this error can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa232674(v=vs.60).aspx). Basically there is too much math happening in a single computation.

To get round this I broke `Cc` it into two parts and this got past the error. I realise this is not the error you displayed in the question but there is a good chance they are related.

Try the below replacement of the `Cc` line of code

```
Cc = n * WorksheetFunction.Pi * (ID / 2) ^ 3
Cc = 1 - (1 / (2 * n + 1)) * (YP / (YP + K * ((3 * n + 1) * q / Cc) ^ n))
```

To confirm, this is replacing the single line beginning `Cc =` with two lines.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just beaten to the post! glad we got there.